# CloudFront: Cache on partial URL

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to configuring CloudFront caching, and I'm wondering how CloudFront will handle the following situation out of the box, or if I can/need to customize my CloudFront configuration.

A user visits `website.com/review/12345/descriptive-title` and is served the page and CloudFront caches it. Another user gets smart and goes to `website.com/review/12345` and is served the same content. Yet another user decides to go to `website.com/review/12345/foo-bar` and gets the same content. To the best of my understanding, each of these `GET` requests would route to `origin` and create a new cached item in CloudFront. I want CloudFront to recognize `website.com/review/12345` and disregard the rest in terms of serving from a cache.

Comment: CloudFront keys off the absolute path in the Url - so you're correct in your assumption that it would treat each one of those requests as unique. Out of interest, why are you concerned about CloudFront not caching the duplicate responses?

Comment: You could always have your origin redirecting to the canonical address for the content (CloudFront will also cache those responses - so doesn't address your original requirement for CloudFront to 'disregard' other requests.